# Get Phone Number List Facet from IContactProcessingContext

Tags: xconnect, marketing-automation

I have a custom activity in marketing automation. Then I try to get phone number when user IContactProcessingContext, but 
context.Contact.GetFacet() return null. Any suggestions as to what I need to do in order to get the Phone Number from PhoneNumberList facet ?

I'm using Sitecore 9.0.2.

My controller:

```
public class SendSMS : IActivity
{
    public IActivityServices Services { get; set; }
    // Parameters
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public ActivityResult Invoke(IContactProcessingContext context)
    {
        string preferredMail = string.Empty;            

        ////get email facet from context contact            



        PhoneNumberList facet = context.Contact.GetFacet<PhoneNumberList>();

        ////exiting activity with failure
        if (facet == null || facet.PreferredPhoneNumber == null)
        {
            return (ActivityResult)new Failure("The Phone Number list Facet Has Not Been Set Successfully");
        }
        string phoneNumber = facet.PreferredPhoneNumber.Number;
        //instantiating email service without DI for simplicity
        var smsService = new SmsService();
        if (!smsService.SendSms(phoneNumber, this.Message))
        {
            return (ActivityResult)new Failure("Failed to send sms message");
        }

        return (ActivityResult)new SuccessMove("true");
    }
```

Comment: Phone numbers facet isn't loaded by default. There is config to add this. I'll answer properly later.

Comment: I look around it and find in the folder : xconnect_root\App_data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Data\Config\sitecore\MarketingAutomation\sc.MarketingAutomation.ContactLoader. But when I add PhoneNumberList the maengine is error. Is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The PhoneNumbers Facet is not included as a default facet expand options in MA

I think I found this for you. The xml configuration file `sc.MarketingAutomation.ActivityTypes.xml` has a section called `IncludeFacetNames` that defines what facets to include when the contact is created. So if you update the section to include the PhoneNumberList facet, it will be there by default.

```
<Options>
    <IncludeFacetNames>
        <Facet1>Emails</Facet1>
        <Facet2>ListSubscriptions</Facet2>
        <Facet3>ContactBehaviorProfile</Facet3>
    </IncludeFacetNames>
    <ExcludeFacetNames />
</Options>
```

to

```
<Options>
    <IncludeFacetNames>
        <Facet1>Emails</Facet1>
        <Facet2>ListSubscriptions</Facet2>
        <Facet3>ContactBehaviorProfile</Facet3>
        <Facet4>PhoneNumbers</Facet4>
    </IncludeFacetNames>
    <ExcludeFacetNames />
</Options>
```

The file can be located here in the root of your xconnect site.

> \xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Data\Config\sitecore\MarketingAutomation\sc.MarketingAutomation.ActivityTypes.xml

Now when the contact loads, phone numbers are there.

[image]

#### The Proper way to patch a config in MA service

Rathen than edit the out of the box xml config files. It is better to patch them. Here is how you do it.

In the folder `\xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Data\Config\sitecore\MarketingAutomation\` create a folder called `custom`. In that folder create a file called `sc.MarketingAutomation.ActivityTypes.xml`. It must be named exactly the same as the file you are patching. In that file, place the xml below and save. Restart the MA windows service.

```
<Settings>
  <Sitecore>
    <XConnect>
      <MarketingAutomation>
        <Engine>
          <Services>
            <MarketingAutomation.Loading.ContactFacetsConfigurator>
              <Options>
                <IncludeFacetNames>
                    <Facet4>PhoneNumbers</Facet4>
                </IncludeFacetNames>
               </Options>
            </MarketingAutomation.Loading.ContactFacetsConfigurator>
          </Services>
        </Engine>
       </MarketingAutomation>
     </XConnect>
   </Sitecore>
</Settings>
```

Comment: I try to inherit BaseActivity but it's changed in Sitecrore 9. I see the document here. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/activity-types.html.

Comment: What type are you inheriting? The inherited type should inherit from BaseActivity at some point.

Comment: I inherit from IActivity, same with doc I comment above. I will update my class in my question

Comment: @ThinhLe I found the answer for your issue

Comment: Yes, it is. You save my day. Thank you too much Chris

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the PhoneNumberList facet which has a facet key of `PhoneNumbers`. You can patch it in by creating a new file that loads after the `xconnect_root\App_data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Data\Config\sitecore\MarketingAutomation\sc.MarketingAutomation.ContactLoader`

```
<Settings>
  <Sitecore>
    <XConnect>
      <MarketingAutomation>
        <Engine>
          <Services>
            <MarketingAutomation.Loading.ContactFacetsConfigurator>
              <Options>
                <IncludeFacetNames>
                  <PhoneNumbers>PhoneNumbers</PhoneNumbers>
                </IncludeFacetNames>
              </Options>
            </MarketingAutomation.Loading.ContactFacetsConfigurator>
          </Services>
        </Engine>
      </MarketingAutomation>
    </XConnect>
  </Sitecore>
</Settings>
```

Comment: Can the patch fie have any name? I thought that patch file needed the same name as the file you are patching. Just loaded later. I guess I can try this.

Comment: It can have any name, but I think it just needs to be alphabetically named so it is loaded later than `sc.MarketingAutomation.ContactLoader`.

Comment: Just tried it 10 ways to sunday. Has to load after the original (so put it in a folder under the current xml config). And MUST be named exactly the same. I tried aaaa.xml and zzzzz.xml. Neither worked. When I named it sc.MarketingAutomation.ActivityTypes.xml again, worked again.

Comment: I have mine in the MarketingAutomation folder named `sc.SendSms.ActivityServices.xml` (it also contains some other definitions). Sitecore 9.1.1.

Comment: Hmmm. I’m in 9.1. Weird part is my custom activity works with any file name. But not the phone facet.

Comment: I try to do this before but when you add facet in sc.MarketingAutomation.ContactLoader and restart the maengine. It will return error.

Answer (score 1):

After creating the Activity Type class and registering your custom activity type and services in Marketing Automation, you'll need to register the **PhoneNumber** facet in Marketing Automation.

By Default, below OOTB facets are registered under Markating Automation:

```
   <IncludeFacetNames>
          <Addresses>Addresses</Addresses>
          <ConsentInformation>ConsentInformation</ConsentInformation>
          <Emails>Emails</Emails>
          <EngagementMeasures>EngagementMeasures</EngagementMeasures>
          <ListSubscriptions>ListSubscriptions</ListSubscriptions>
          <Personal>Personal</Personal>
          <InteractionsCache>InteractionsCache</InteractionsCache>
    </IncludeFacetNames>
```

Now, To register the other contact facets in `ContactLoader` config patch. Create a new patch file `sc.MarketingAutomation.ContactLoader.xml` at below path *<path_to_xconnect>\App_Data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Data\Config\sitecore\MarketingAutomation_patch*

(Note: I've created a new folder named **MarketingAutomation_patch** to include all patches for marketing automation under this folder.)

```
<Settings>
 <!--
   Marketing Automation contact loader configuration
-->
 <Sitecore>
   <XConnect>
     <MarketingAutomation>
       <Engine>
         <Services>
           <MarketingAutomation.Loading.ContactFacetsConfigurator>
             <Options>
               <IncludeFacetNames>
                 <PhoneNumbers>PhoneNumbers</PhoneNumbers>
               </IncludeFacetNames>
             </Options>
           </MarketingAutomation.Loading.ContactFacetsConfigurator>
         </Services>
       </Engine>
     </MarketingAutomation>
   </XConnect>
 </Sitecore>
</Settings>
```

I've covered all the steps in details to create a new custom action in Marketing Automation and deployment here: https://sitecorewithraman.wordpress.com/2021/04/25/sitecore-marketing-automation-custom-action-part-iii/